# How do you override `GetHashCode()` idiomatically for an algebraic data type?

Tags: hash, f#

I have an algebraic type of the following form:

```
type Example =
    | Ctor0 of int
    | Ctor1 of Example * Example
    | Ctor2 of Example * Example
    | Ctor3 of Example list
```

If I need to hash a value of type `Example`, I can use the default method: `myValue.GetHashCode()` or use `hash` which does the same thing. Now, suppose I want to define my own hash function for some reason because I need a special hash for the `Ctor3` constructor, then I would override the `GethashCode()` method:

```
type Example =
    | Ctor0 of int
    | Ctor1 of Example * Example
    | Ctor2 of Example * Example
    | Ctor3 of Example list

override this.GethashCode() =
    match this with
    | Ctor0 (n) -> hash n (* The default `hash` is sufficient here *)
    | ...
    | Ctor3 (xs) -> myCustomHash xs
```

I need to define a hash value for `Ctor1` and `Ctor2`, but their form is similar and using `hash` would not help. Indeed, for example one could define `Ctor1(Ctor 7, Ctor 4)` and `Ctor2(Ctor 7, Ctor 4)` if, in `GetHashCode()`, I hash only the value of the constructors, I would have the same hash for two different values.

```
override this.GetHashCode() =
    match this with
    | Ctor0 (n) -> hash n
    | Ctor3 (xs) -> myCustomHash xs

    (* I could do something like that: *)

    | Ctor1 (a, b) -> hash a + hash b  (* or maybe  1 + hash (a, b) *)
    | Ctor2 (a, b) -> hash a - hash b  (*           2 + hash (a, b) *)
```

The latter code does not seem to me very satisfactory... In such a situation, and assuming I have a large number of constructors, how am I supposed to define a hash function that of course produces a different value for each constructor (with a high probability anyway)?

I don't know much about hash algorithms, so my question may be very silly, but an indication of the idiomatic way to define (override) the hash function for this style of situation would be appreciated.

PS: I know you have to use `CustomEquality` and `NoComparison`, I'm just talking about how to do what I want here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way to combine hash codes since .NET Standard 2.1 is using `System.HashCode.Combine()`. To differentiate between cases, you can add an integer argument.

```ml
override this.GetHashCode() =
    match this with
    | Ctor0 n -> HashCode.Combine(0, n)
    | Ctor1 (a, b) -> HashCode.Combine(1, a, b)
    | Ctor2 (a, b) -> HashCode.Combine(2, a, b)
    | Ctor3 xs -> HashCode.Combine(3, myCustomHash xs)
```

I added the integer argument in all cases for consistency, but I think you're right that `Ctor0` and `Ctor3` don't really need it.

If you need to be compatible with older .NET versions, you can rely on `hash` for tuples instead. (I'm using struct tuples here which should allocate less than normal tuples)

```ml
override this.GetHashCode() =
    match this with
    | Ctor0 n -> hash struct(0, n)
    | Ctor1 (a, b) -> hash struct(1, a, b)
    | Ctor2 (a, b) -> hash struct(2, a, b)
    | Ctor3 xs -> hash struct(3, myCustomHash xs)
```

Comment: I didn't know about `HashCode.Combine`, thanks for that :)